# I have problem to get items from cart model using nested URL

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm working on multi vendor online store project using django , I'm trying to get items from cart but I get not found response

I use nested URL :

```
app_name = "cart"

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        "cart_retrieve/<str:pk>/items/",
        CartItemsRetrieveView.as_view(),
        name="retrieve-cart-items",
    ),
]
```

so I have this view to get the items from the cart :

```
class CartItemsRetrieveView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Cart.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CartSerializer
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Assuming the cart is identified by a cart_id in the URL
        cart_id = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        try:
            cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=cart_id)
            return cart.items.all()  # Return all items related to the cart
        except Cart.DoesNotExist:
            return CartItems.objects.none()
```

the problem is when I commented the get_queryset I can retrieve the cart object :

```
{
    "cart_id": "75ed487e-445a-437c-aef6-4cf62217e6e7",
    "created_at": "2023-08-20T12:15:56.360320Z",
    "items": [
        {
            "cart_items_id": "b2fe23bc-442c-41fb-be8d-65f9f03241ae",
            "cart": "75ed487e-445a-437c-aef6-4cf62217e6e7",
            "product": {
                "product_id": "463d4e16-46a2-4da0-9e25-2a99a494b6f6",
                "title": "el short el fashe5",
                "discounted_price": 90.0
            },
            "quantity": 1,
            "sub_total": 90.0
        },
        {
            "cart_items_id": "8bf66b5b-2b9d-4dd3-8528-cfc693035168",
            "cart": "75ed487e-445a-437c-aef6-4cf62217e6e7",
            "product": {
                "product_id": "5fecf90c-874b-452f-8a8d-adde50ee2f33",
                "title": "cover lel 2amar",
                "discounted_price": 50.0
            },
            "quantity": 2,
            "sub_total": 100.0
        },
        {
            "cart_items_id": "140a0762-17ef-4e65-aa1a-997b79fec14b",
            "cart": "75ed487e-445a-437c-aef6-4cf62217e6e7",
            "product": {
                "product_id": "e6e61a33-82cc-40f7-aef7-f538150bb703",
                "title": "mouse bs nice",
                "discounted_price": 33.25
            },
            "quantity": 3,
            "sub_total": 99.75
        },
        {
            "cart_items_id": "2f569234-bc7d-4d2c-ad49-d4a6bbe9cc4b",
            "cart": "75ed487e-445a-437c-aef6-4cf62217e6e7",
            "product": {
                "product_id": "7c3c2692-fe2c-4aae-9323-d344e7da825e",
                "title": "el short el fa2e3",
                "discounted_price": 36.0
            },
            "quantity": 2,
            "sub_total": 72.0
        }
    ],`your text`
    "grand_total": 361.75
}
```

but with the method I got not found so I guess the problem is in the get_queryset method

Comment: can you please show the serializer for the cart?

Comment: can you please share the Cart and Cart Items Model.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM:**

1. Actually whatever queryset you will provide to **RetrieveAPIView**, it finds the particular entry in database which matches queryset (list of objects) **primary key** with URL parameter `pk`.
2. ***So as you are overriding the `get_queryset` method and returning all cartitems list to queryset, so it will check for all the cartitems id with `URL parameter pk`, and in this case `pk is cart_id` which will never match with `cart_item_id`***.
   That's why it's not able to find any entry.

**SOLUTION:**

*You have to use **ListApiView**.*

```
class CartItemsRetrieveView(generics.ListApiView):
    serializer_class = CartSerializer # instead of cart serializer create another serializer for Cart-Items
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Assuming the cart exists with a cart_id in the URL
            cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=self.kwargs["pk"])
            return cart.items.all()  # Return all items related to the cart
```